# why is this footer not at the end of the content?

Tags: css, css-float

Main markup

```
<body>
  <div id="contenedor">
      ....
  </div>
  <div class="fLeft"> <footer > ... </footer> </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
}
#contenedor{ float: left; width:100%;}
.fLeft{ float:left }
```

I guess best way is to firebug the page..

```
http://209.51.221.243/integracion/login.php
```

As you can see, the footer is above the middle of the page behind the content...

Comment: Note that HTML5 does not allow self-closing tags in most cases: http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/

Comment: Well it was only to reproduce the markup, i will edit it...

Comment: I don't see the purpose of wrapping a div around the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I thought it might be that you didn't clear your float. But then I noticed that each floated element is absolutely positioned. By applying `position:absolute` to an element, you're ripping it out of the flow of the document. The best way to fix this is to remove `position:absolute` from your "widgets", but then your design won't appear how you currently have it.

An idea/suggestion to workaround your limitations is to fix the footer to the bottom of the page. Apply the following to `<footer>`:

```
footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

You'll notice that your footer will stay put as you scroll on the page, and that can very possibly be less than ideal, but I can guarantee it'll stay on the bottom of the page. Otherwise, you're looking at reworking your styles because of the misuse of some properties.

Comment: So i can't fix this with css?

Comment: i would rather position:absolute it.. i need it at the bottom of the page (not the viewport). But thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Well then, as I mentioned, you'll have to re-do your layout for all intensive purposes. There is no way for the container nor the footer to know where the "widget" elements end because `position:absolute` has ripped them from the flow of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You use floating divs before footer, so, in order to put the footer after those divs, the css of your footer should contain: `clear: both;`, or `clear: left;`, in your case.

Docs: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp and (of, course) https://www.google.com/search?q=css+clear :)

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE2: I realized I was wrong. This answer does not work in this particular case.

---

First: [This](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) is a pretty good starting point for any footer. Use it.

Second: You may have noticed that the container that has all the floating boxes (`.centerCnt`) isn't big enought to fit them all. To fix this you need to use a good `.clearfix`. There are many to choose from, but I use [this](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/) one:

```
/* The Magnificent Clearfix: Updated to prevent margin-collapsing on child elements. - j.mp/bestclearfix */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
/* Fix clearfix: blueprintcss.lighthouseapp.com/projects/15318/tickets/5-extra-margin-padding-bottom-of-page */
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

You will need this on `.centerCnt` otherwise the Sticky Footer won't work.

UPDATE: Simply using the clearfix would probably fix your issue. Add the code above to your CSS and give `.centerCnt` the class `clearfix`.